# UITableViewCell Not Autoresizing in "Live" Search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uisearchbar

## Little Bit of Background

I am in the process of making a search feature for some announcements in my app. I load the initial announcements in a `UITableView` with a custom cell to display. To achieve a dynamic cell size in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the `AnnouncementTableViewController` class I use the autoresizing technique:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

That works perfectly for displaying the cells with various heights. Calling `tableView.reloadData()` when refreshing the cells' data works great.

I have a different `UITableView` that initially displays a blank tableview and a `UISearchBar` as a header. I implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`, perform my search filter logic and append filtered announcements to a `filteredAnnouncements` array.

I call the `tableView.reloadData()` method in the `didSet` for the `filteredAnnouncements`.

## The Issue

When I type in the search bar the cells do not automatically resize themselves, in fact they are the default height. I have a title and a body for each announcement, so the body just gets cut off.

[image: UITableViewCells cut off the body of the announcement]

## What I've Tried

The `UITableAutomaticDimension` trick doesn't seem to work for a live search (that updates after each keypress). I've tried calling `tableView.setNeedsDisplay()`, `tableView.setNeedsUpdatedConstraints`, `tableView.setNeedsLayout()` in the `didSet` observer of the `filteredAnnouncements` array.

I've tried to override the `didMoveToSubview()` method in the custom cell's class to call those different methods named above as per an old stackoverflow question, all with no luck.

## Edit: Answered Own Question Below

Comment: Did you set true constraints inside your custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overriding the `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` and returning the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`. I changed the method to:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.estimatedRowHeight
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on the table will force it recalculate the heights for all rows.

I think you'll find the whole experience much easier (and more pleasing to your users!) if you implement the row insertion/deletion methods of `UITableView` instead of using `reloadData`.

Comment: Where should I call the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`? I put them after the `reloadData` method in the `didSet` of the `filteredAnnouncements` and the cells did not resize. And thanks for the tip regarding the insertion/deletion methods. I've been going off basic tutorials and did not realize those methods existed